# Preprocessing .txt files for NLP

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have a upwards of a hundred unstructured .txt files (articles) that I need preprocess for NLP, must I convert the .txt files to .csv files first? Or can I start scrubbing with the raw text file? If so, can anybody help me with batch file type conversion with Python?

Comment: I see that this is your first question, so please familiarize yourself with these FAQs and repost your question -- (1) How do I ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- (2) How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should be fine with .txt files to get the text from them. Further processing depends on the task you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no need of converting text files to csv. You can easily read a word file using python.docx. In order to do it first you need to install python.docx.
in python 3:

```
!pip install python.docx  //install python docx

from  docx import Document  //import docx

doc=open("TextFileName.docx","rb") //creating a word file object

document=docx.Document(doc) //creating word reader object
```